# Error when installing a further Wordpress within an already existing Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, configuration, installation, bluehost

I read that's possible to have two Wordpress installations, one within the other one. Specifically, I have a first Wordpress site in my root location:

```
https://wpsite1.com
```

(this installation was automatically accomplished by the hosting service, Bluehost, when I bought their hosting space). Then I created a sub-directory and manually installed another Wordpress:

```
https://wpsite1.com/wpsite2
```

The `.htaccess` file of `wpsite1.com` is showed below:

```
# Use PHP5.6 as default
# AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 10 minutes"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 3 hours"
</IfModule>
Header set X-Endurance-Cache-Level "2"
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php70” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

while the `.htaccess` file of the **new second installation** `/wpsite2` is the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wpsite2/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wpsite2/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

As you can see, the sub-directory exists in `RewriteBase` and `RewriteRule`. However, if I visit both locations I receive now the following error:

> "The file 'wp-config.php' already exists. If you need to reset any of
>   the configuration items in this file, please delete it first. You may
>   try installing now."

and the status code is `500`:

[image]

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to install another wordpress instance in a separate directory.

you need to create a folder in root directory with name "wpsite2" and need to install the second wordpress instance inside it. and you need to map database to it.

then you can access the https://wpsite1.com/wpsite2

It's better to call up or chat with the support team of bluehost.

you can refer this.

[Create subdomain](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/274)

the above mentioned things are for another wordpress install.

if you want two wordpress instances in same wordpress install you can refer "**Multisite**" in wordpress.

[Multisite example](http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/multisite/)

Comment: That's exactly what I did.